Route LLM implementation OpenAI API key error
I'm trying to implement a simple Route LLM Module using OpenAI and Groq. I keep getting an error saying "openai.OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable".
import os
from routellm.controller import Controller
from rich import print

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "My secret openai key"
os.environ["GROQ_API_KEY"] = "My secret key"

client = Controller(
    # List of routers to initialize
    routers=["mf"],
    # The pair of strong and weak models to route to
    strong_model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    weak_model="anyscale/mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1",

    # This config for the router is provided by default and is the best-performing config.)
    config={
        "mf": {
            "checkpoint_path": "routellm/mf_gpt3.5_augmented"
        }
    },
    # Display a progress bar for operations
    progress_bar=False,
)

def llm_query_router(query):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
      # This tells RouteLLM to use the MF router with a cost threshold of 0.11593
      model="router-mf-0.11593",
      messages=[
        {"role": "user", "content": f"{query}"}
      ]
    )
    return f'Model - {response["id"]} \nResponse - {response.choices[0]["message"]["content"]}'

response_message=llm_query_router("What are the benefits of eating healthy food")
print(response_message)

I've used this API key for a LiteLLM implementation and it works fine. Not sure why it's not working here.
